# How can I get a part of page content with PHP?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'd like to get (for example) the first article from a webpage. How should I get that?
I tried to use file_get_contents(), but after that I couldn't do anything with that.

Comment: i have to be careful not to make my comment longer than the question. this question has no real context, you want to get data from 1 website and display it on your website ? have you some code you would like to share ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't do anything with that"? You have the content, that is what you wanted to get. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DOM parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// headings
 foreach($html->find('h1') as $element) 
     echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
     echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: If OP doesn't know it yet, will need to download the library http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/ and use `include_once('simple_html_dom.php');` - It's not stated in the manual/link you provided.